# Show Woocommerce breadcrumbs on Category page

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the most current version of Woocommerce. I have breadcrumbs showing on a product page, but I want these displayed on a Category page also. Is there a hook for this? or do I need to edit a template file?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code somewhere in your theme php files:

```
       <?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>
```